# Hive regexp_replace on multiple columns

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I am using a hive query which has many columns, and I need to replace the comma character in all columns.
There are hundreds of columns, some numeric, some text, and doing it one by one one will take me a long time.
So is there something like:

```
select regexp_replace (*, ',','')
```

...where the `*` denotes all columns?

Comment: Hm, if this is a one-off job, you could simply use `describe tablename;` and 'build' the required quires in your favorite text editor (or even a spreadsheet using autofill). It may sound cumbersome, but I guess it takes you there quickly.